# Symfony 2 security issues with multiple providers, multiple firewalls and multiple hosts

Tags: symfony, symfony-security

I have some issues setting up Symfony 2's security.
I currently have this in my security.yml

```
security:
encoders:
    Acme\AdminBundle\Entity\AdminUsers:
        algorithm: bcrypt
    Acme\UserBundle\Entity\Users:
        algorithm: bcrypt

role_hierarchy:
    ROLE_USER:        ROLE_USER
    ROLE_ADMIN:       ROLE_USER
    ROLE_SUPER_ADMIN: [ ROLE_ADMIN, ROLE_ALLOWED_TO_SWITCH ]

providers:
    provider_admin:
        entity: { class: AdminBundle:AdminUsers, property: username }
    provider_user:
        entity: { class: UserBundle:Users, property: username }

firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false

    login:
        pattern: ^/login$
        security: false
        anonymous: ~

    recover:
        pattern: ^/(recover-password|generate-hash)$
        security: false
        anonymous: ~

    secured_area:
        pattern:   ^/
        provider: provider_admin
        host: admin.example.dev
        form_login:
          check_path: /login_check
          login_path: /login
          always_use_default_target_path: false
          default_target_path: /
          username_parameter: _username
          password_parameter: _password
        logout:
          path:   /logout
          target: /
        anonymous: ~

    public_secured_area:
        pattern:   ^/dashboard
        host: app.example.dev
        provider: provider_user
        form_login:
          check_path: /dashboard/login_check
          login_path: /login
          always_use_default_target_path: false
          default_target_path: /dashboard
          username_parameter: _username
          password_parameter: _password
        logout:
          path:   /public/logout
          target: /login
        anonymous: ~

access_control:
    - { path: ^/dashboard/*, roles: ROLE_USER }
    - { path: ^/*, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }
```

As you can see, I have 2 different providers, 2 different firewalls and 2 different hosts.
That's because I need to log users from the Users table on app.example.dev and users from the AdminUsers table on admin.example.dev.

This is what I have in my **admin** routing.yml:

```
login:
  path: /login
  host: admin.example.dev
  defaults: { _controller: UserBundle:Security:login }
login_check:
  path: /login_check
  host: admin.example.dev
logout:
  path: /logout
  host: admin.example.dev
```

And this is what I have in my **app** routing.yml

```
public_login:
  path: /login
  host: app.example.dev
  defaults: { _controller: PublicBundle:Default:login }

public_login_check:
  path: /dashboard/login_check
  host: app.example.dev

public_logout:
  path: /dashboard/logout
  host: app.example.dev
```

The way it's setup now everything works correctly on the admin side.
On the app side the logout doesn't work, it says:

```
Unable to find the controller for path "/dashboard/logout". Maybe you forgot to add the matching route in your routing configuration?
404 Not Found - NotFoundHttpException
```

They seem to be setup in a similar manner and yet the solution for this is for me to setup an actual controller in the **app.** logout route, add a logout action with actual logout and redirect code for this to work. 
Which tells me something is wrong. Any idea what that is?

Also logging in didn't work at first either because I the 2 entries in the access_control section of the security.yml files were reversed until I read the docs again and I understood that the paths in there need to be listed from particular to general.

So my second question is about this: is there no way to tie an access_control entry to a certain firewall or at least to a host?

EDIT:
Although I got the answer, see below, but I would still like to understand whether my last question, 2 paragraphs above this, is a valid one.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Change `public_secured_area` firewall like this:

```
public_secured_area:
    ...
    logout:
      path:   /dashboard/logout
      target: /login
    anonymous: ~
```

or change app routing like this:

```
public_logout:
  path: /public/logout
  host: app.example.dev
```

Both route and logout path should be the same..

Comment: Yes, you are right and what's even more annoying to me is that I KNOW that the logout route needs to be behind the firewall, but apparently despite spending 30 minutes formularting this question I missed the wrong logout path in security.yml. I had changed things so much over the past days that I lost track of that /public url. Thank you.